# Почему нельзя использовать такую фразу: "Выйдя из дома, свет заполнил все пространство"?

Tags: деепричастный-оборот, правила

Пишу рассказ, поспорили с другом. Он утверждает, что можно использовать такой оборот: "Выйдя из дома, свет заполнил все пространство" (в контексте "человек вышел из дома и видит свет"). Я считаю, что нельзя так писать, но разъяснить правильно почему, не могу. Очень нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: Неправильно согласованный деепричастный оборот - один из примеров [*анаколуфа*](https://kovalev-copyright.ru/russkiy/chto-takoe-anakoluf.html). Также в [wiki](https://wikepedia.me/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%84)

Answer (score 2):

> Если... производитель действия, обозначенного глаголом-сказуемым, и
> производитель действия, обозначенного деепричастием, ***не** совпадают*,
> употребление деепричастного оборота стилистически **ошибочно**

(Розенталь и др., СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ, 1999; см. §212. п.1: Деепричастные обороты) http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02

В вашем случае "выйдя" по смыслу относится к человеку (подразумеваемому), а "заполнил" - к свету. Формально же (грамматически) выходит, что *свет вышел из дому и заполнил пространство*.

Comment: С ответом согласен, но не хватает одной детали. Какой бы вы вариант правки преложили? Вопрос с подвохом, предупреждаю. Но больше пока говорить ничего не буду.

Comment: Например, после оборота можно вставить "он ощутил, как..." Неплохо бы и пространство ограничить словесно (доступное взору, между собором и баней и т. п.)..

Comment: То есть ***"Выйдя из дома, он ощутил, как свет заполнил все пространство”***? Логической неувязки не видите? Или не воспринимаете, что при таком построении фразы "заполнение светом" оказывается обусловленным выходом из дому? Если уж не в причинно-следственном аспекте, то как минимум - в логически-временнОм. Нет? Вопрос не праздный, давно, со времен чеховской слетевшей шляпы, подозревал, что в подобных ляпах следует винить не только нарушение грамматики, но и непонимание говорящим внутренней логики событий. А тут пример - как нельзя кстати. Что скажете?

Comment: Неувязка могла быть в случае "ощутил, что..." (будто сравнивал помещение с улицей), а здесь беспричинная последовательность событий: сначала (или как только) вышел, ощутил перемены на улице - как (или насколько) изменилось освещение, напр. после того как нанятые работники закончили развешивание фонарей по аллее.

Comment: *сначала (или как только) вышел* - неправда ваша. Вы забыли или упустили главное. "Свет ***заполнил***".

Comment: *Неувязка могла быть в случае "ощутил, что..." (будто сравнивал помещение с улицей),* - а это вообще не понял. При чем тут сравнение посещения с улицей? И само по себе спорно, и невязка не в том. "Он вышел из дома - и увидел, что/как выпал снег" - почуЙствуйте разницу.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо. Спорить не могу, ибо не имею четко сформулированной позиции, идущей дальше соображения, что здесь есть внутренняя семантика логической обусловленности, носителями более или менее ощущаемая, но, вероятно, нигде и никем пока не описанная.

Answer (score 0):

Деепричастные конструкции строятся по определенным правилам, на которые вам уже указали.

Но зачем вам деепричастный оборот, последовательность действий можно записать иначе, а также дополнительно обозначить  резкий переход с помощью тире, например:

***Вышел из дома — и свет заполнил все пространство**. Он видел только ослепительно сияющий дневной свет.*

**Пояснение**

Человек, входящий со стороны света в тёмное помещение, или наоборот, выходящий из тёмного помещения на яркий свет, первое время ничего не видит и лишь затем начинает различать окружающие предметы.

Вот как это объясняется https://otvet.mail.ru/question/89477734